# Oracle : "parsing failed" error when creating an auto_increment trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, auto-increment, database-trigger, database-sequence

I'm trying to make an **auto_increment trigger** for the IDs of an Oracle database.
After some research, I found a way to write one using a **sequence** and a **before insert trigger**.

Problem is, when I execute the trigger, I have the following error :

> Parsing failed for:
>   
>   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AUTO_INC_PDE_ITINERAIRE
>   BEFORE INSERT 
>   ON PDE_ITINERAIRE 
>   FOR EACH ROW 
>   BEGIN 
>   SELECT PDE_ITINERAIRE_ID_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL
>   INTO

If I use the following command :

```
select * from SYS.USER_ERRORS where name = 'AUTO_INC_PDE_ITINERAIRE';
```

It returns the following output :

> Line 3 | Pos 10 | PLS-00201: identifier 'NEW.PDE_ITINERAIRE' must be declared
>   Line 2 | Pos 03 | PL/SQL: SQL statement ignored
>   Line 4 | Pos 03 | PL/SQL: ORA-00904 invalid identifier

Here is the full query for the trigger :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AUTO_INC_PDE_ITINERAIRE
BEFORE INSERT 
ON PDE_ITINERAIRE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT PDE_ITINERAIRE_ID_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL
INTO   :NEW.PDE_ITINERAIRE.ID_PDE_ITINERAIRE
FROM   dual;
END;
/
```

I'm not really used to Oracle's triggers, so could someone help me finding out what is wrong in my trigger ?

Thanks for your time

### EDIT

I changed the trigger from your advice

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AUTO_INC_PDE_ITINERAIRE
BEFORE INSERT 
ON PDE_ITINERAIRE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :NEW.ID_PDE_ITINERAIRE := PDE_ITINERAIRE_ID_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL;
END;
/
```

I still have the same error output though.
More informations :
--Oracle is v11.
--TOra 3 is used as IDE.

### EDIT 2

Here is the DDL as asked :

> CREATE TABLE "GEOMAP"."PDE_ITINERAIRE" 
>      (    "ID_PDE_ITINERAIRE" NUMBER(11,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
>       "NOM_ITINERAIRE" VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
>       "LONGUEUR" NUMBER(15,4), 
>       "INSEE_DEPART" VARCHAR2(5), 
>       "INSEE_ARRIVEE" VARCHAR2(5), 
>       "TYPE_ITINERAIRE" VARCHAR2(30), 
>       "TYPE_BALISAGE" VARCHAR2(30), 
>       "COULEUR_BALISAGE" VARCHAR2(55), 
>       "NOM_TOPO_GUIDE" VARCHAR2(255), 
>       "ANNEE_TOPO_GUIDE" VARCHAR2(4), 
>       "DATE_DERNIER_ENTRETIEN" DATE, 
>       "PERIODICITE_PREVUE" VARCHAR2(30), 
>       "DATE_PROCHAIN_ENTRETIEN" DATE, 
>       "ORGANISME_ENTRETIEN" VARCHAR2(60), 
>       "OBSERVATIONS_ENTRETIEN" VARCHAR2(30), 
>       "CREATEUR" VARCHAR2(55), 
>       "COUT_TOTAL" VARCHAR2(50), 
>       "DATE_DECISION_CP" DATE, 
>       "SUBVENTION_ITINERAIRE" NUMBER(8,2), 
>       "SUBVENTION_TOPO" NUMBER(8,2), 
>       "OBSERVATIONS_ADMIN" VARCHAR2(255), 
>       "HEBERGEMENT" VARCHAR2(30), 
>       "MONUMENTS" VARCHAR2(30), 
>       "OBSERVATIONS_TOURISTIQUES" VARCHAR2(30), 
>       "GEOMETRIE" "MDSYS"."SDO_GEOMETRY" , 
>       "COMMUNE_DEPART" VARCHAR2(55), 
>       "COMMUNE_ARRIVEE" VARCHAR2(55), 
>       "FICHIER_TOPO_GUIDE" VARCHAR2(255)
>      )

Comment: try: select PDE_ITINERAIRE_ID_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL into :NEW.ID_PDE_ITINERAIRE from dual;  If that doesn't work, post the exact error message

Comment: This is what I did already, like I wrote above the first Edit section.
The exact error is the first quotation.

Comment: No, you actually have :NEW.PDE_ITINERAIRE.ID_PDE_ITINERAIRE in your code, I just removed the reference to PDE_ITINERAIRE and have :NEW.ID_PDE_ITINERAIRE  .  The error suggests it cannot resolve the identifier PDE_ITINERAIRE (identifier 'NEW.PDE_ITINERAIRE' must be declared).  Simple to try and see if it fixes the problem anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed !
I finally downloaded Oracle SQL Developer to check my trigger in another IDE, and it proposed me to link a value (NEW) when i executed it.
This last trick did the job.

I assume either Tora does not execute pl/sql properly, or maybe I missed a declaration for :NEW and SQL Developer fixed it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

`:new` is a record containing all columns of the trigger's table, so you can't include the table name when referencing it:

`:NEW.PDE_ITINERAIRE.ID_PDE_ITINERAIRE` should be `:NEW.ID_PDE_ITINERAIRE`

Additionally, you don't need the `select`, you can simply assign the value (at least with any supported version of Oracle):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AUTO_INC_PDE_ITINERAIRE
BEFORE INSERT 
ON PDE_ITINERAIRE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   :NEW.ID_PDE_ITINERAIRE := PDE_ITINERAIRE_ID_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you for the early reply, I just updated the query the way you advised. I still have the same error output though.
Btw my Oracle is version 11.

Comment: The error suggests that there is no such column in the table, maybe a typo? Can you please add the table DDL as well.